# verify if a view was displayed even if for a moment

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I have a login UI with a corresponding API call in my code, which I want to test using Espresso. When I click on the login button, an API call is made and a ProgressBar appears for as long as the API call is executing and then it's visibility is set back to gone once we get a response. Most of the times, the call is very instantaneous, hence if I check for isDisplayed() on the ProgressBar view, I get false. Below is the code -

```
    onView(withId(R.id.edit_text_username)).perform(typeText("asd"));
    onView(withId(R.id.edit_text_password)).perform(typeText("asd"), closeSoftKeyboard());
    onView(withId(R.id.forward_button)).check(matches(isEnabled()));
    onView(withId(R.id.forward_button)).perform(click());

    onView(withId(R.id.progress_bar_gateway)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Is there any way to check if the ProgressBar visibility was toggled from gone -> visible -> gone?

Comment: what you want to make visible and gone and when??

Comment: a ProgressBar, to be shown when the login API call is executing

Comment: are you using asynctask??

Comment: I'm using RxJava + Retrofit

Comment: I am not familiar with these!! Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You should check uiautomator - [uiwatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiWatcher.html) . Uiautomator runs on instrumentation. So you can have your uiwatcher code inside espresso.

Now coming to your situation- The idea is to detect ui change in `ProgressBar visibility`. Register a watcher for this activity and you can add your `"what to do code" at gone -> visible -> gone` .

sample code-

```
public class watchProgressbar implements UiWatcher {

   public boolean checkForCondition() {
    //Add uiautomator code to detect the visibility change of pregress bar.
    //Add what you want to do when a state change is detected.

    }

}
```

Hope this helps.An [example](http://qathread.blogspot.kr/2015/05/espresso-uiautomator-perfect-tandem.html) where uiautomator and espresso used together.

Comment: UiWatchers only execute if UiAutomator can't find a match during a findObject(...) call. Unfortunately, they won't help for this use case.